# Adding new X session on vt8 results in black screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, tty, virtual-console

I'm trying to add another X session on vt8, for testing a window manager under different conditions without interfering with my regular session. I've done this in the past by simply running `startx -- :1 -nolisten tcp vt8`, but this does not appear to work on this laptop.

To simplify things, i've tried the following:

```
xinit  /usr/bin/xterm -- :1
```

from (text console) vt1. This switches to vt8, as it's the first unused vt, and the screen goes black. I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to my regular X session, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> to go back to the black screen, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to the text console where I can see the X start-up messages, etc.

The `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` start-up details are identical to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (except for the time stamps) and only differs right at the end where the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F*</kbd> keystrokes are toggling modes. Also, `ps` shows `X` is running, as is the `xterm`, and `xdpyinfo` lists details (though, oddly, with a 640x480 screen size). The screen, however, remains black.

Note that this IS a change from what was there before... the previously empty vt8 at least had a backlight on, and a cursor blinking in the top left corner. This returns when I quit the X session. While it's running, though, the screen turns completely dark on vt8.

Is there perhaps something more that needs to be done to get this X session working? This laptop is running Ubuntu 15.10, and has intel and nvidia video cards (with the nvidia-settings set to use the nvidia card for rendering, actual display handled by the intel one). I don't know if that matters, or if this configurations needs some additional tweaks for this to work, but as I mentioned, the `Xorg.1.log` file doesn't show anything different when it comes to loading drivers, etc.

Any ideas? Suggestions for anything else to look at? Thanks!